# How to store multiple image with text box values in PHP?

Tags: php, html

I want a program to store path of  multiple image into database along with html text box values. I have tried but I can't be able to store same text values for multiple images.can someone help me!!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and correct your question due to instruction.

Comment: Could you please show your code?

Comment: show your efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the following steps for uploading multipe images using same input text values.

Step 1: Create Database Table

```
CREATE TABLE `images` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `text_box_value` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `file_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `uploaded_on` datetime NOT NULL,
 `status` enum('1','0') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Step 2: Database Configuration (dbConfig.php)

```
<?php
// Database configuration
$dbHost     = "localhost";
$dbUsername = "root";
$dbPassword = "";
$dbName     = "your_db_name";

// Create database connection
$db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

// Check connection
if ($db->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error);
}
?>
```

Step 3: File Upload Form HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>Multiple Image Upload</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            Input Value:<br>
            <input type="text" name="text_box_value"><br><br>
            Select Image Files to Upload:<br>
            <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple ><br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="UPLOAD">
        </form> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Step 4: Upload Multiple Files in PHP (upload.php)

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    // Include the database configuration file
    include_once 'dbConfig.php';

    // File upload configuration
    $targetDir = "uploads/";
    $allowTypes = array('jpg','png','jpeg','gif');
    $text_box_value = $_POST['text_box_value'];
    $statusMsg = $errorMsg = $insertValuesSQL = $errorUpload = $errorUploadType = '';
    if(!empty(array_filter($_FILES['files']['name']))){
        foreach($_FILES['files']['name'] as $key=>$val){
            // File upload path
            $fileName = basename($_FILES['files']['name'][$key]);
            $targetFilePath = $targetDir . $fileName;

            // Check whether file type is valid
            $fileType = pathinfo($targetFilePath,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            if(in_array($fileType, $allowTypes)){
                // Upload file to server
                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$key], $targetFilePath)){
                    // Image db insert sql
                    $insertValuesSQL .= "('".$text_box_value."', '".$fileName."', NOW()),";
                }else{
                    $errorUpload .= $_FILES['files']['name'][$key].', ';
                }
            }else{
                $errorUploadType .= $_FILES['files']['name'][$key].', ';
            }
        }

        if(!empty($insertValuesSQL)){
            $insertValuesSQL = trim($insertValuesSQL,',');
            // Insert image file name into database
            $insert = $db->query("INSERT INTO images (text_box_value, file_name, uploaded_on) VALUES $insertValuesSQL");
            if($insert){
                $errorUpload = !empty($errorUpload)?'Upload Error: '.$errorUpload:'';
                $errorUploadType = !empty($errorUploadType)?'File Type Error: '.$errorUploadType:'';
                $errorMsg = !empty($errorUpload)?'<br/>'.$errorUpload.'<br/>'.$errorUploadType:'<br/>'.$errorUploadType;
                $statusMsg = "Files are uploaded successfully.".$errorMsg;
            }else{
                $statusMsg = "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
            }
        }
    }else{
        $statusMsg = 'Please select a file to upload.';
    }

    // Display status message
    echo $statusMsg;
}
?>
```